# How to drive segment display and sens button press at the same time? Understanding this schematic

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, pnp, 7segmentdisplay

I have a very simple board that has been designed by the Italians back in 2001.
It has 3 7segment common anode displays, 2 buttons, and a few LEDs.

I have to interface with it but I don't know how it works.

P3 is just and IDC connector that used to connect to the CPU board.
LED[3..5] are the display modules.

I guess the PNPs are switching the anode of the displays, driven by Cathode[a..f] pins, the LEDs use the same principle, but I think i got that right.

What I don't understand is that how can I sense if the switch S[3..4] has been pushed if it is connected to a pulsating Output. I am planning to use a TM1637 to drive the displays but I am very lost on how to find out when the button has been pushed with a simple ESP32 module.

Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: If I lead the connected end of the buttons to VCC through a resistor, and also to the MCU, it would behave like a weird pull-up switch when PNP_SR1 is LOW, but it would be an oscillating signal, and would be hard to find out which button was pressed...

Comment: First at all, I wonder how p-n-p transistors can control backward biased LEDs in their emmiters (p-n-p transistor collectors should be connected to ground). Maybe, transistors operate in the so-called "reverse active mode" where the CE voltage is lower. Then, the cathode segments should be controlled through resistors. Buttons are read when the according SR signal is low - if the button is pressed, the common button point will have low (0.7 V) voltage. Of course, this point should be "pulled up" by another resistor connected to +V. Buttons are separated by the D2 and D3 decoupling diodes.

Comment: TM1637 has a provision for a matrix keypad .... modify the circuit and place the switches between P3-15 and the segment lines ... question: are the transistors oriented correctly?

Comment: Good idea, I'd love that, but this board has been made for 20 years now and I can't change the layout anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-n-p transistors Q3-Q5 work in the so-called "reverse active mode" where the collector and emitter are swapped. The advantage of this weird connection, as far as I can remember from 80s, is that the collector-emitter voltage of the saturated transistor is lower than in the case of the conventional *active mode* connection. The cathode segments should be controlled through additional resistors in series.

The buttons S3 and S4 are read when the according SR signal is low - if the button is pressed, the common button point will have low (0.7 V) voltage. Of course, this point should be "pulled up" by another resistor connected to +Vcc. Buttons are separated by the D2 and D3 decoupling diodes.

Comment: "The cathode segments should be controlled through additional resistors in series." What do you exactly mean by this? Can't I just hook it up to TM1637 like on page 8 here:"https://www.mcielectronics.cl/website_MCI/static/documents/Datasheet_TM1637.pdf"

Comment: I had a similar idea, but this way I'd have to use 3 pins to "watch" these 2 buttons. Also, I 'd have to use 3 voltage dividers to use it with and ESP32, and compare the signals. 
Is there no more "elegant" way? 
Maybe a circuit to remove this comparison task from the MCU?

Although if I haven't had Interrupt in all my pins, this circuit would be beneficial. 
Also thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: LEDs, like any diode, are voltage stabilizers; so, in any case they should be driven *by current* (in the simplest case, by voltage through resistance to set the current). If TM1637 provides this feature, it can directly drive them. Why do you need to compare signals?

Comment: Here is a possible software solution to see what of the buttons is pressed. Think of each button-diode network as an AND logic gate with two inputs - SR1,2 voltages driving base resistors and S3,4 voltage of the common point. It is а "reverse AND" with active zeros at the input and output. So, continuosly read the voltage of the common point (or use it as an interrupt signal). If it is low, then read the SR voltages to see what is low (what of the buttons is pressed). You need 3 port inputs to read these signals.